# Widget with collections, how to update RemoteView after loading data from the internet?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I am learning to work with widgets with collections. I am loading scores from the internet asynchronously and after I load the data I would like to update the view however, my code skips over the updating the view part. I've tried several things but it doesn't wait for the async to finish it makes calls to the other callback methods before the list can get populated.

WidgetDataProvider.class

```
public class WidgetDataProvider implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

List<SportScores> mSportScores;

Context mContext = null;

public WidgetDataProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    mSportScores = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    initData();
    Log.i(FetchServiceConstants.WIDGET, "SPORT SCORES SIZE = " + mSportScores.size());

}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    initData();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mSportScores.size();
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    Log.i(FetchServiceConstants.WIDGET, "GET VIEW AT");

    RemoteViews mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),
        R.layout.football_scores_widget);

    mRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.home_name_widget,
        mSportScores.get(position).getHomeName());

    mRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.away_name_widget, mSportScores.get(position).getAwayName());
    mRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.score_textview_widget, mSportScores.get(position).getScore());
    mRemoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.away_crest_widget, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        mContext.getResources(), Utilies.getTeamCrestByTeamName(mSportScores.get(position).getAwayName())
    ));

    mRemoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.home_crest_widget, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        mContext.getResources(), Utilies.getTeamCrestByTeamName(mSportScores.get(position).getHomeName())
    ));

    mRemoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.home_name_widget, Color.BLACK);
    mRemoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.score_textview_widget, Color.BLACK);
    mRemoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.data_textview_widget, Color.BLACK);
    mRemoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.away_name_widget, Color.BLACK);

//        mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.list_item_layout_widget, pendingIntent);
    return mRemoteViews;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

private void initData() {
    mSportScores.clear();

    new async().execute();

    Log.i(FetchServiceConstants.WIDGET, "intit DATA ");
}

private Cursor getTodaysScores() {
    Log.i(FetchServiceConstants.WIDGET, "todays scores");
    return mContext.getContentResolver().query(
        DatabaseContract.scores_table.buildScoreWithDate(),
        null,
        null,
        new String[]{PagerFragment.getDate(4)},
        null);
}

private void addScoresToList(Cursor scoreCursor) {
    Log.i(FetchServiceConstants.WIDGET, "Loggint info");

    if (scoreCursor == null) {
        Log.i(FetchServiceConstants.WIDGET, "cursor = null");
    } else {
        Log.i(FetchServiceConstants.WIDGET, scoreCursor.getCount() + "");
    }

    scoreCursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!scoreCursor.isAfterLast()) {

        SportScores newSportScore = new SportScores(
            scoreCursor.getString(scoresAdapter.COL_HOME),
            scoreCursor.getString(scoresAdapter.COL_AWAY),
            Utilies.getScores(
                scoreCursor.getInt(scoresAdapter.COL_HOME_GOALS),
                scoreCursor.getInt(scoresAdapter.COL_AWAY_GOALS))
        );

        mSportScores.add(newSportScore);
    }
}

private void update_scores() {
    Intent service_start = new Intent(mContext, myFetchService.class);
    mContext.startService(service_start);
}

private class async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        update_scores();
        addScoresToList(getTodaysScores());
        Log.i(FetchServiceConstants.WIDGET, "in back");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

     //update remote views after scores have been updated
     //NOT SURE WHAT TODO HERE
    }
}
}
```

WidgetService.class

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {

    WidgetDataProvider dataProvider = new WidgetDataProvider(
        getApplicationContext(), intent);
    return dataProvider;
}
}
```

FootballScoresWidget.class

```
public class FootballScoresWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews mView = initViews(context, appWidgetManager, widgetId);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, mView);
        Log.i(FetchServiceConstants.WIDGET, "ON UPDATE ");
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private RemoteViews initViews(Context context,
                              AppWidgetManager widgetManager, int widgetId) {

    RemoteViews mView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
        R.layout.football_widget_list);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);

    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    Log.i(FetchServiceConstants.WIDGET, "intit views ");
    mView.setRemoteAdapter(widgetId, R.id.widgetCollectionList, intent);

    return mView;
}
}
```

How do I go about updating the widget list view after the data has been loaded or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Same question here! Any updates on this?